# ERROR: dependency 'askpass' is not available for package 'credentials' while installing "ssh"

Tags: r, ssh, credentials

I am trying to install `ssh` in `R` version `3.2.5` of windows 10, and 
I am getting the below error, can any one help me what could be wrong here?

```
install.packages("ssh")

#>The downloaded binary packages are in
#        C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpq0Bnkq\downloaded_packages
#installing the source package ‘credentials’

#trying URL #'https://mirror.its.sfu.ca/mirror/CRAN/src/contrib/credentials_1.1.tar.gz'
#Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 229147 bytes (223 KB)
#downloaded 223 KB
```

> ERROR: dependency 'askpass' is not available for package 'credentials'
>   * removing 'C:/Users/xyz/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/credentials'
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>           ‘C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpq0Bnkq\downloaded_packages’
>   Warning messages:
>   1: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.5/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\xyz\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users\xyz~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpq0Bnkq/downloaded_packages/credentials_1.1.tar.gz' had status 1 
>   2: In install.packages("ssh") :
>     installation of package ‘credentials’ had non-zero exit status

**Edit:**

I have tried the below command suggested by RAB

```
install.packages("ssh", dependencies=TRUE)
```

but unfortunately still I am getting similar error:

> ERROR: dependency 'askpass' is not available for package 'credentials'
>   * removing 'C:/Users/xyx/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/credentials'
>
> ERROR: dependency 'stringr' is not available for package 'knitr'
>   * removing 'C:/Users/xyx/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/knitr'
>
> ERROR: dependencies 'knitr', 'stringr' are not available for package 'rmarkdown'
>   * removing 'C:/Users/xyx/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/rmarkdown'
>
> ERROR: dependency 'knitr' is not available for package 'spelling'
>   * removing 'C:/Users/xyx/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/spelling'

Comment: use `install.packages("ssh", dependencies=TRUE)`

Comment: thanks for suggestion RAB, but unfortunately i am still getting the similar error, i have updated the question with the logs.

Comment: a few things to try: 1) update to a newer version of R, the dependency might not be available for such an old version. 2) see if you have a corrupted version of the `credentials` package in your library, and if so manually delete it, 3) try install the `askpass` package by itself and see if the error is any different, 4) check you have write permissions to the folder where your library is stored.

Comment: also, go through every error you posted above and manually try and install the package rather than as a dependency (eg `install.packages(knitr)`)